# All the possible outcomes

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this

```
gen<-c("A","B","C")
prob<-c("0.95","0.82","0.78")
mw<-c("10","20","50")
df<-data.frame(gen,prob,mw)

 gen prob mw
1   A 0.95 10
2   B 0.82 20
3   C 0.78 50
```

Now I want to have all the possible outcomes of (A,B,C), (A,B),(A,C),(B,C),(A),(B),(C),(NONE) with the probabilities for example (A,B,C)=0.95*0.82*0.78= 0.60762.

```
trials <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=length(gen)))
for(i in 1:length(gen)){
  trials.tmp <- t(combn(gen,i))
  trials <- rbind(trials,cbind(trials.tmp, matrix(nrow=nrow(trials.tmp),      
  ncol=length(gen)-i ) ))
  }
 trials

V1   V2   V3
1  A <NA> <NA>
2  B <NA> <NA>
3  C <NA> <NA>
4  A    B <NA>
5  A    C <NA>
6  B    C <NA>
7  A    B   C
```

But still I'm missing the combination (NA,NA,NA). How can I make a new data frame with all outcomes and probabilities.

Comment: Look into `combn` and `prod` functions, and `lapply` for looping.

Comment: Still not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try  `combn` as mentioned by zx8754, for example

```
a=0.95
b=0.82
c=0.78
x <- c(a,b,c)
df <- rbind(t(combn(x, 3)), cbind(t(combn(x, 2)), NA), cbind(t(combn(x, 1)), NA, NA))
apply(df, 1, function(x) prod(x[!is.na(x)]))
[1] 0.60762 0.77900 0.74100 0.63960 0.95000 0.82000 0.78000
```

Comment: What's `combinat` for? That code looks like `base` R.

Comment: `combinat` is for permutations and combination of elements

Comment: @Mot4 avoid asking new questions. This was not a requirement at the beginning.